# Custom authorization service not being used, even though it is declared in services

Tags: c#, blazor

In Blazor:

I am creating a custom AuthenticationStateProvider class so I can use a custom user database hosted on mssql. My custom class is:

```
public class ServerAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    string UserId;
    string Password;

    public void LoadUser(string _UserId, string _Password)
    {
        UserId = _UserId;
        Password = _Password;
    }


    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var securityService = new SharedServiceLogic.Security();

        var userService = new UserService();

        var validPassword = await securityService.ValidatePassword(UserId, Password);

        var authenticated = validPassword == true ? true : false;


        var identity = authenticated
            ? new ClaimsIdentity(await userService.GetClaims(UserId), "AuthCheck")
            : new ClaimsIdentity();

        var result = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
        return result;
    }

}
```

I then register it in Startup.cs:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
        services.AddAuthorizationCore();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
 }
```

My App.razor is:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Startup).Assembly">
        <NotFoundContent>
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </NotFoundContent>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Now I want to use the service in Index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@using BadgerWatchWeb.Services
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

<h1>Sup</h1>


<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <h1>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</h1>
        <p>You can only see this content if you're authenticated.</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <h1>Authentication Failure!</h1>
        <p>You're not signed in.</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorizing>
        <h1>Authorizing</h1>
    </Authorizing>
</AuthorizeView>


@code {
    [CascadingParameter] Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    AuthenticationState AuthState;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        AuthenticationStateProvider.LoadUser("mperry", "testtest");
        AuthState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(AuthState);
    }

}
```

I cannot run this code because of an error. The error says `AuthenticationStateProvider does not contain a definition of LoadUser`. I thought that the service would be able to use the classes in ServerAuthenticationStateProvider. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ServerAuthenticationStateProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/057ec9cfae1831f91f1a0e01397059b20431db7b/src/Components/Server/src/Circuits/ServerAuthenticationStateProvider.cs)  is the name of the default AuthenticationStateProvider added by Blazor in server-side Blazor [configuration](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5e575a3e64254932c1fd4937041a4e7426afcde4/src/Components/Server/src/DependencyInjection/ComponentServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) , and indeed, it does not contain a definition of LoadUser

This is what Steve Anderson has to say about customizing AuthenticationStateProvider

> For server-side Blazor, it is very unlikely that you should implement
>   a custom AuthenticationStateProvider. The built-in implementation
>   already integrates with ASP.NET Core's built-in authentication
>   mechanisms. If you implement a custom one, you may introduce security
>   vulnerabilities.

I'd suggest you read through the ServerAuthenticationStateProvider class, understand what it does and how, follow the whole process, and then decide whether or not to create a customized AuthenticationStateProvider

Hope this helps

Comment: But if I want to use a custom table to implement the login, don't I need a custom AuthenticationStateProvider?

Comment: Are you using the Identity UI ? If you do, I guess it would be sufficient to change the name of the table. See the documents how to do that. If not, you'll have to  implement the whole process by your own. That is, validate the user against the custom table, and pass the user's credentials (ClaimsPrincipal) to your custom AuthenticationStateProvider which should derives from the ServerAuthenticationStateProvider class. Would you mind marking it as the answer if it answered  your question, so others know it was useful.

Comment: I marked this as the correct one since your the only one who bothered to answer my question. But if I rename the class to something else, I still get this issue.

Comment: The "built in" one doesn't even give acces to raw JWT token, so yeah, there is a need to implement a custom one